# "Error Creating Control" when using Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am designing a form using the SP designer 2007. I am getting the following error on of my control

[image]

Is there any fix for this please?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the solutions in the links -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2007/03/22/error-creating-control-when-using-microsoft-office-sharepoint-designer-2007.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/2b837df5-0c83-4401-8cbd-51dacf0dd0f2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've seen this before and that it was caused by including a column in the form where the user doesn't have permission to the list for a lookup. Since you haven't included 
any  information about your list, I can only guess that this the the cause here as well.